# Swagger doesn't work with specific named models

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger

Im having trouble with getting swagger to work with my models. I have an endpoint which takes in an object which has a property that takes an `RequestActionType` enum.

I get the `Failed to load API definition` `Internal Server Error .../swagger.json` error. BUT if I change the name of the pr `RequestActionType` it works fine.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you check the ``Schema`` section in generated ``swagger.json`` file? maybe there is a duplication

Comment: where do i find the swagger.json?

Comment: It's based on your swagger setup, but usually its here ``http://localhost:{port}/swagger/v1/swagger.json``

Comment: this page doesn't work, "This page isn’t working right now localhost can't currently handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500".

Comment: please share how you add swagger in startup

Comment: also it shown in swagger homepage

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that I had the same enum in two places, but with different namespaces. After doing a bit more research, I found that by default swagger uses just the class name as a schemaId. So the above will throw an error due to duplicate class. To get swagger to use the full namespace we need to set the below code in the startup.cs when configuring swagger.

```
c.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);
```